# Thymeleaf Form Action with selected item's value as a request params

Tags: forms, action, thymeleaf

i have a thymeleaf form with select options in it, i want to add the select options value (contains id of the object) as a request parameter of the form action address,
here's the selection part of the form:

```
<select th:field="*{caseCategory}">
<option th:each="case : ${caseCategoryList}" th:value="${case.caseCategoryId}" th:text="${case.caseCategoryName + ' - ' + case.caseCategoryCode}"></option>
</select>
```

how to add the value of selected item to the form action address as a request parameter,
here's the action address,

```
var actionCheck = /*[[@{/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add}]]*/ '/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add';
$('#memberRkiForm').attr('action',actionCheck).submit();
```

i'm expecting the address like this:

```
var actionCheck = /*[[@{/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&caseCategory=VALUE OF SELECTED ITEM}]]*/ '/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&caseCategory=VALUE OF SELECTED ITEM';
```

please help me how to add request params like that, thx in advance,
sorry for my less of knowledege.

Answer (score 0):

Send the form using HTTP `GET` method. This will transfer your form data as URL parameters.

```
<form th:action="@{/memberrki/checkCardNum}" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
    <select name="caseCategory">
        <option th:each="case : ${caseCategoryList}" th:value="${case.caseCategoryId}" th:text="${case.caseCategoryName + ' - ' + case.caseCategoryCode}"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, after clicking the submit button, the browser would send request to the URL **/memberrki/checkCardNum?action=add&caseCategory=VALUE OF SELECTED ITEM**